# Can a JavaFX ChoiceBox be forced to always expand menu below the control?

Tags: javafx

When this choicebox is expanded the first time, it drops down below the control as it is expected to, as you can see here:

[image: Choicebox expanding downward]

However, once you have selected an item, and then go back to expand the ChoiceBox, it expands UPWARD, like this:

[image: ChoiceBox expanding upward]

I'd like to force it to always expand downward, is this possible?

Edit:  Per request, here is a simple reproducable example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.*;

public class SimpleForm extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        stage      = new Stage();
        scene      = new Scene(anchorPane, width, height);
        start();
    }

    private AnchorPane        anchorPane;
    private Stage             stage;
    private Scene             scene;
    private double            width  = 300;
    private double            height = 550;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
    private Label             label;

    public void start() {
        choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox.setPrefWidth(150);
        label = new Label("User Name");
        String                 item1 = "<New User>";
        String                 item2 = "John Doe";
        String                 item4 = "Jane Doe";
        String                 item3 = "Jack Doe";
        ObservableList<String> list  = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.addAll(item1, item2, item3, item4);
        choiceBox.setItems(list);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(label);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(choiceBox);
        Node node1 = anchorPane.getChildren().get(anchorPane.getChildren().indexOf(label));
        Node node2 = anchorPane.getChildren().get(anchorPane.getChildren().indexOf(choiceBox));
        setNodePosition(node1, 20, -1, 20, -1);
        setNodePosition(node2, 20, -1, 50, -1);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void setNodePosition(Node node, double left, double right, double top, double bottom) {
        if (top != -1) setTopAnchor(node, top);
        if (bottom != -1) setBottomAnchor(node, bottom);
        if (left != -1) setLeftAnchor(node, left);
        if (right != -1) setRightAnchor(node, right);
    }

}
```

Oboe recommended that I use a VBox, so here is another example using his code, the behavior is the same ... when you click on any item other than the first one, then go back and expand the ChoiceBox, it expands UPWARDS, or more accurately, it uses the selected item as the CENTER of the list putting everything above that item above the control and everything below the item below the control. I want it to always put the list below the control.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;

public class SimpleForm extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        stage      = new Stage();
        scene      = new Scene(anchorPane, width, height);
        start();
    }

    private AnchorPane        anchorPane;
    private Stage             stage;
    private Scene             scene;
    private double            width  = 300;
    private double            height = 550;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
    private Label             label;

    public void start() {
        choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox.setPrefWidth(150);
        label = new Label("User Name");
        String item1     = "<New User>";
        String item2     = "John Doe";
        String item4     = "Jane Doe";
        String item3     = "Jack Doe";
        VBox   container = new VBox();
        container.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
        container.setSpacing(10);
        List<String> items = List.of(item1, item2, item3, item4);
        choiceBox.getItems().addAll(items);
        container.getChildren().addAll(label, choiceBox);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(container);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra - Updated with a simple reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific layout I would use VBox instead of AnchorPane:

```
    Label label = new Label("User Name");
    ChoiceBox<String> cb = new ChoiceBox<>();
    
    VBox container = new VBox();

    container.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
    
    container.setSpacing(10);

    List<String> items = List.of("<New User>", "EasyGoing1");
    
    cb.getItems().addAll(items);
    
    container.getChildren().addAll(label, cb);
```

On the other hand, in a `ChoiceBox`, the popup will move to line up the item  that matches the one in the `ChoiceBox`. If you add more items you'll see the effect. I guess that's the intended behavior to avoid the need to scroll to selected item.

Comment: I tried it with a VBox and the behavior is the same

Comment: I updated the question with the code modified to implement your code ... it still does the same thing

Comment: Michael, I see what you mean. In a ChoiceBox, The popup will move to line up the item  that matches the one in the ChoiceBox, with the one in the ChoiceBox. If you add more items you'll see the effect. I guess that's the intended behavior to avoid scrolling to the selected item.

Comment: Yes, I just now changed the code to use a ComboBox and it behaves as I want it to ... I was not expecting that. I guess my solution is to just use a ComboBox ... wonder why JavaFX has both controls ...

Comment: I agree, I never use a ChoiceBox ;)  I edited my answer with the popup behavior explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Oboe was correct, if I use a ComboBox instead of a ChoiceBox, the control behaves as I want it to. After looking up the difference between the two, I think a ComboBox will suit my needs just fine.

Thank you Oboe.

If anyone is interested, here is the code behaving as desired:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;

public class SimpleForm extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        stage      = new Stage();
        scene      = new Scene(anchorPane, width, height);
        start();
    }

    private AnchorPane       anchorPane;
    private Stage            stage;
    private Scene            scene;
    private double           width  = 300;
    private double           height = 550;
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
    private Label            label;

    public void start() {
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setPrefWidth(150);
        label = new Label("User Name");
        String item1     = "<New User>";
        String item2     = "John Doe";
        String item4     = "Jane Doe";
        String item3     = "Jack Doe";
        VBox   container = new VBox();
        container.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
        container.setSpacing(10);
        List<String> items = List.of(item1, item2, item3, item4);
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(items);
        container.getChildren().addAll(label, comboBox);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(container);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```